# Selinux policy to allow all access to script or to not log anything done by this script

Tags: selinux, auditd

I have a bash script running every 5 minutes in cron, that basically runs some commands like: `mkdir, top, grep, date, wait, sleep, jstack`. It runs on user `bob`.

It generates a lot of logs and I want to filter it out from auditd. This script has to run on user `bob`, so I cannot create a new user for this script specifically and filter by the user. I also want to keep other logs generated by `bob`. I have tried to change selinux policy for a custom made policy and unfilter it by specifying this policy in auditd rules. It works fine, however many more logs are now generated due to selinux denies. I have adjusted the policy further with the info I got from audit logs, however it finds another context needed almost every day.

My question is: how can I make a custom policy that allows pretty much everything but label it as let's say  `test_script_t` to filter it out. I do not want to turn off Selinux, but I want to lower logs amount.